# what is structure of oracle composite index

Tags: oracle

I was looking in oracle concepts documentation, but found nothing about how compound index is designed in oracle rdbms, whether it's a structure of subtrees or a concatenation of fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is by default b-tree however, the Oracle database provides specialized indexes that can provide additional capabilities; the bit-mapped index and the function-based index. See more detail [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_easysql_btree_index.htm)